# Xcode: Image showing original size in simulator

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

I have created some images in UIViews and in scrollviews in a UIViewController. I go to run the app and the images are in scale but have blown up to there original size.

Interface Builder

[image]

Simulator

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click the image in IB, you see a dropdownlist in the left menu called `mode` in the `Utillities` pane. There I believe you should choose "Expect fit" or "Expect fill", unsure which you should use. When you choose that mode, the image should not rescale.

I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello Paul, thanks for the reply, yeah, so I have turned on Aspect Fill.... and it sill makes the error.

Comment: Ok, try others. You might find the correct one there in between.